# Syntax error, unexpected ',' when trying to seed in Laravel 5.6 using cmd

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations, laravel-seeding

I'm trying to follow a tutorial on using command prompt in Windows. It's called [Laravel Tutorial: Step by Step Guide to Building Your First Laravel Application](https://laravel-news.com/your-first-laravel-application) and I'm stuck in seed :

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TestingTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
  public function run()
  {
    factory:(App\Testing::class, 5)->create();
  }
}
```

I already tried solutions from other question on Stack Overflow but I'm unable to fix the error.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
factory(App\Testing::class, 5)->create();
```

instead of

```
factory:(App\Testing::class, 5)->create();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the factory function wrong, remove the colon(:) after that as:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TestingTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
       factory(App\Testing::class, 5)->create();
    }
}
```